# SPARK - How can I parse a column to timestamp?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In spark, I'm trying to parse a column which has the following format : "yyyyMMddHHmmss" into a timestamp format so that I can query the data with group by day or group by hour.

I already tried many things but I'm not really sure about what I wrote because I didn't find so mush doc.

```scala
test = spark.read.json("dataJson/xxx/xxx/*.gz")

test1 = test.withColumn("Date", to_date(unix_timestamp(test.col("dh")," yyyyMMddHHmmss").cast("timestamp")))
```

But the only result I'm having is

```
test1.select("Date").show()
+----+
|Date|
+----+
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
+----+
```

By the way I tried first to do it in scala because it is the only documentatio I found but I'd like to do it in python.

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert string date to `timestamp` as simply with `unix_timestamp` as

```
df.withColumn("newDate", unix_timestamp($"date","yyyyMMddHHmmss").cast("timestamp"))
```

I see the space before dateformat which can cause issue

Hope this hepls!

Comment: Thank you so much it worked in scala ! Do you have an idea of what would be the <$"date"> in python ?

Comment: it means column, may be you could replace with `df('date')` or can use `col("date") by importing functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of date() function. below is the sample snippet

```
val someDF = Seq(
  (8, "19890614121212"),
  (64, "19890614121212"),
  (-27, "19890614121212")
 ).toDF("number", "my_date")


val test1 = someDF.withColumn("my_Date1", 
unix_timestamp($"my_date","yyyyMMddHHmmss").cast("timestamp"))

test1.show()
```

Comment: What us the difference with other answer here ?